# MatDialog not rendering inside custom OverlayContainer in angular 15

Tags: angular, angular-material, overlay, mat-dialog

In Angular 15, if a component is provided with OverlayContainer and overridden to use it as a custom container element, individual overlay elements are not rendering inside the container (), instead is appended to the document body(default behaviour).

```
@Injectable()
export class OverlayService extends OverlayContainer{
    constructor(
      @Inject(DOCUMENT) _document: any,
      platform: Platform,
      private problem: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
    ) {
      super(_document, platform);
    }

    protected override _createContainer(): void {
      const containerClass = "cdk-overlay-container";
      const container = this._document.createElement("div");
      container.classList.add(containerClass);

      this.problem.nativeElement.appendChild(container);
      this._containerElement = container;
    }

}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-problem',
  templateUrl: './problem.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./problem.component.css'],
  providers: [
    DialogServiceService,
    MatDialog,
    { provide: OverlayContainer, useClass: OverlayService },
  ],
})
```

Current behaviour:

```
<body>
  <app-problem></app-problem>
</body>
<div class="cdk-overlay-container">
  <mat-dialog-container></mat-dialog-container>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pfwikb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproblem%2Fproblem.component.ts

I was expecting the MatDialog to render inside the custom container as in previous angular versions.

Expected behaviour:

```
<body>
 <app-problem>
   <div>....</div>
   <div class="cdk-overlay-container">
      <mat-dialog-container></mat-dialog-container>
   </div>
 </app-problem>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't migrated any of the apps to v15 (and probably won't anytime soon), so I can't give you full working solution - but perhaps I will at least be able to push you in the right direction.

If you take a look at the [constructor of MatDialogBase](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/dialog/dialog.ts#L104) you'll notice that while `OverlayContainer` is still injected, it's documented as deprecated and no longer used. That's why your `MatDialog` is still rendered in the default `cdk-overlay-container`.

`MatDialog` docs don't mention anything about changing the container in which the dialog will be rendered. If you dig a little bit deeper into the source you'll see that it will be rendered in the `MatDialogContainer` - but it seems that this is not configurable as it's explicitly typed in `MatDialog` and not exposed in the `MatDialogConfig`. So unless I'm missing something (and it's quite possible I am), you can't change the container anymore. I think your best bet is create an issue in the github of `angular/components` [repo](https://github.com/angular/components) - if there's a way, I'm sure you get a response from them with an example, especially since it seems like a huge regression.

Luckily, since v14 there is an alternative to `MatDialog` - namely `CdkDialog` upon which it's built. In there, the [DialogConfig](https://material.angular.io/cdk/dialog/api#DialogConfig) exposes a `container` property, which allows you specifying a component type or factory for a component in which the dialog will be rendered. The downside is that you'll lose the material styling and will have to apply your own.

Comment: Thank you, I have created an issue in GitHub for angular/components.

Answer (score 0):

this tip work like charm after 4 days of searching for solution

```
in your CSS file add this style : 


    .mat-mdc-dialog-container {
   position: fixed !important;
   top:0  !important;
   bottom: 0  !important;
   left: 0  !important;
   right: 0 !important;
   display: flex !important;
   width: 50% !important;
   height: 50% !important;
   margin: auto  !important;
}
```